# Access secured servlet from EJB in same EAR

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I have EAR project which contain web-module and EJB-module. Ejb-module try to connect to servlet using standard Java SE utility classes (`URL`, `HttpConnection`).

But my servlet is secured using `<security-constraint>` and `<security-role>` sections in `web.xml`. So when EJB try access to servlet I always get `Not authorized error (401)`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you expect us to know what your security constraint is? Need to be a particular user, need to provide some specific certificate, need to make the request from a specific IP? etc. Without this information it would be hard to do anything better than a stab in the dark.

Comment: @rdcrng this is not make sense. Main idea is that application is not authorized to use servlet. So I need make authentication/authorization in code.

Comment: Yes, but to authenticate and authorize, you need to know what the conditions for said authorizations need to be.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your servlet. You haven't told us anything about what kind of authentication mechanism it expects. For exmple, there are the basic ones `BASIC`, `DIGEST`, (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617) `FORM` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form-based_authentication), `CERTIFICATE` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate); and there are the more complicated ones like `OAuth`. Each has different procedures for authentication, then you also need to provide the right credentials to gain the right authorization.

Comment: Why would you want to access the servlet from EJB?